# Calendly API booking meetings for an user

Tags: intercom, calendly

I have been reading through the [Calendly API](https://developer.calendly.com/docs/api-use-cases) docs and I am trying to figure out if there is a way to programmatically create a meeting event for a user.

We have intercom installed on our site, but we want a more native approach to scheduling a meeting. Is there any way to create a meeting with Calendly through the api using a round robin method. Wasn't sure how to just by reading the docs linked above.

Comment: The direct answer to your question is "no", but Calendly does have a native [Intercom integration](https://calendly.com/pages/integrations/intercom) that may make things more seamless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I work for Calendly. There's not an API to programmatically schedule events, and probably won't be for a while. You can review the latest API documentation and submit feedback at https://developer.calendly.com/.

**UPDATE 1**

While there's still not a public API for scheduling events, we now have a public API endpoint to [List Available Slots for an Event Type](https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/6a1be82aef359-list-event-type-available-times). You can use it to deepen an integration between Calendly and your app, like presenting a custom availability schedule. However, the final booking will still have to be done through Calendly.

**UPDATE 2**

There are also two more API endpoints that may be helpful:

1. [List User Busy Times](https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/5920076156501-list-user-busy-times) - use it to get a User's "raw" availability, outside of the scope of a particular Event Type. Returns a list of busy time slots for a given User and date range.
2. [List User Availability Schedules](https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/8098de44af94c-list-user-availability-schedules) - use it to get e.g. default working hours of a User in an Organization.

Comment: Just wondering, why is this the case? It would open up many more possibilities if this was available.

Comment: In short, there are numerous variations of our booking flow and we're not ready for a stable public API around it. That said, we'd love to learn more about your use case in more detail if you're willing to send us an email at support+developer@calendly.com

Comment: Thank you for the response @DmitryPashkevich - is there a simpler API, for simply listing what are the bookable times for a user? I'm trying to create an alert when one of the users in my org becomes unbookable (eg because they misconfigured something).

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a public API for getting users' booking availability either, but we're collecting feedback on the matter. Feel free to send a note to the above email address to be the notified of any updates.

Comment: An API for programmatically scheduling events is hardly missed. I reverse engineered your booking web page and was able to schedule events from within our iOS App, without using a WebView. But suddenly it requires a re-captcha after some request. I will get in contact  with your support. If we can't schedule using our App, we may have to switch to another calendar/appointment service.

Comment: The internal APIs used in the Calendly web app are not meant for third party use and are subject to change without notice. Please know that your feedback is considered, but as of right now, there is not a publicly available API for booking events.

Comment: @jkff we now have an API to list event type availability https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/6a1be82aef359-list-event-type-available-times

Comment: @DmitryPashkevich I know that this is internal and that it might change at any time. I appreciate that there finally is an official API for getting available slots for an event type. I also did that with the unofficial "API" but will now switch to the mew, official one. But again: Having an API for booking events would be very welcome!

Comment: @DmitryPashkevich We could use the official booking URL of an event if we knew all parameters. So far I know that it is possible to give date, email and name. But the booking page is always asking for a time slot. If we could bypass this, we could use the booking url in a WebView within our App. If we had a page were the user only needs to confirm, Date, Time, eMail and Name, we could use it. I'd appreciate if you cold tell me all Query-Parameters available to the booking URL.

Comment: Ah! I just have to add Date and Time to the path of the booking URL. Like /2022-10-04T10:15:00+02:00?name=<>&email=<>&timezone=<>. Then I directly get to the booking details page for the desired time slot with all details already pre-populated and the user just has to klick the "Booking" button. Maybe I can "click" that button programmatically so our users don't even need to see that confirmation page. This is so complicated and could be so much easier with an API!

Comment: @JoachimDeelen the Event Type Availability endpoint (https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/6a1be82aef359-list-event-type-available-times) returns a `scheduling_url` for each time slot, so you shouldn't need to build that URL yourself.

Comment: @DmitryPashkevich is there a way to get a user's availabilities for a specific even type? for example, if I have a link https://calendly.com/[USER]/[Event_Type], can I get their availabilities via the API? They are not part of our organization and I don't want to scrape the page if possible

Comment: @Jorjani there is currently not an API to get the Event Type availability as an "anonymous" invitee, for someone that's not a User in your Calendly Organization

Comment: If you have connected let say google calendar. Then you can book an event in google calendar, and calendly will automatically synchronise calendars and remove unavailable slots.